# SQL multiple active jobs query

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the part of the db I am working with.

- `cont_employee` (emp_no PK, emp_fname, emp_lname, birth_date)
- `contract` (contractor_no PK, emp_no,job_no,is_active)

So I'm trying to put together a query that will show me employees who have worked on more than one active job. So far I have managed to write a query that will get me a list of people who are working on one or more active jobs.

```
SELECT 
   cont_employee.*,contract.*
FROM 
   cont_employee
JOIN 
   contract ON contract.emp_no = cont_employee.emp_no
WHERE 
   is_active = 1
```

I'm not really sure how to progress from this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some sort of aggregation.  Here is my recommendation, assuming that `is_active` is in the `contractor` table and that is what you really mean in your query:

```
SELECT ce.emp_no
FROM cont_employee ce JOIN
     contractor c
     ON c.emp_no = ce.emp_no
WHERE c.is_active = 1
GROUP BY ce.emp_no
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```